# How to show different background-images randomly for multiple divisions of same class name

Tags: javascript, background-image

I am currently working on credit card UI.
I've been trying to randomly change the background-image of multiple divisions(class names are the same).
My intention is showing different image randomly for each division on reload the page, but I end up with the same image(random, though) for all target divisions.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Current code is as below(style is not written here).

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="card-inner"></div>
<div class="card-inner"></div>
<div class="card-inner"></div>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
        var url = [];
        url[0] = 'card-bg1.jpg';
        url[1] = 'card-bg2.jpg';
        url[2] = 'card-bg3.jpg';
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * url.length);
        var elm = document.querySelectorAll('.card-inner');
        for (let i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
             elm[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/service/' + url[n] + ')';
         }    
    }
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! This i because you use the same `url[n]` for each `elm[i].style.background`, so it add the _same_ (random) image to each background. Try to use `'url(../img/service/' +url[(n+i)%url.length]+')'`. I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move

```
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * url.length);
```

inside the loop like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * url.length);
  elm[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/service/' + url[n] + ')';
}
```

How can you expect it will be different if you call it once?

If you want them to be unique, you can use code like this, removing chosen element from urls array each time

```
function () {
  const urls = [] 
  const elm = document.querySelectorAll('.card-inner');
  for (let i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
    if (!urls.length) {
      urls.push('card-bg1.jpg', 'card-bg2.jpg', 'card-bg3.jpg');
    }
    const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length);
    const url = urls.splice(n, 1).pop()
    
    elm[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/service/' + url + ')';
  }    
}
```

PS Looks strange using var and let together. If you use let, then use const for non-changable variables

Comment: In this way, with only 3 images, it is easy to have duplicates backgrounds. But it still is a solution ^^

Comment: It is not clear in qiestion that they should be unique, but okay, i will try to give this solution as well

Comment: Thanks both of you ! I am sorry that I did not make it clear if I want it to  be unique.Yes,I want it to be unique, so your answers helped me a lot!